Pygatt BGAPIError: Unable to auto-detect BLED112 serial port
This is a code to toggle on bluetooth on windows when I try executing the code it is giving me this error raise BGAPIError("Unable to auto-detect BLED112 serial port")
pygatt.backends.bgapi.exceptions.BGAPIError: Unable to auto-detect BLED112 serial port
import pygatt
from pygatt.backends import BGAPIBackend
 
def toggle_bluetooth(enable):
    state = 'on' if enable else 'off'
    subprocess.run(f"powershell.exe (Get-Service bthserv).StartType='{state}'", shell=True)
    print(f"Bluetooth turned {state}")
 
def scan_ble_devices():
    adapter = BGAPIBackend()  # Use BGAPI for Windows with Bluegiga adapters
    try:
        adapter.start()
        devices = adapter.scan(timeout=10)
        for device in devices:
            print(f"Found BLE device {device['name']} with address {device['address']}")
    finally:
        adapter.stop()
 
# Turn Bluetooth on
toggle_bluetooth(True)
 
# Scan for BLE devices
scan_ble_devices()
 
# Optionally turn Bluetooth off after scanning
toggle_bluetooth(False)



You are mixing completely different things in your software. On the one hand, you are using the tools of the Windows Bluetooth stack to switch on and off any Bluetooth hardware built into your computer.
On the other hand, you are trying to control a very specialised USB dongle that your computer knows nothing about except that it has a serial port ...
Judging by the error message, you have either not plugged in the BLED112 USB dongle at all or have not installed the needed driver.
If the BLED112 USB dongle is nevertheless present and correctly installed, it is also possible to manually assign the serial interface of the BLED112 dongle to the instance
adapter = pygatt.BGAPIBackend(serial_port='COM9')

how can I use the integrated BLE module present in a laptop? Instead of a dongle

You could change your operating system to Linux, then the library you are using would work. https://github.com/peplin/pygatt?tab=readme-ov-file#pygatt---python-module-for-bluetooth-le-generic-attribute-profile-gatt

What if I want to use windows and the BLE module inside the laptop, can you suggest any changes I make in the code?

You should have read the link I posted in my last comment. The library you have chosen will only work with Windows if you use the BLED112 USB dongle.
